# Flutter Table Calendar : Showing Event from API

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show Calendar and including event, the event already exists from API. I searching plugin fit to my case and I found Table Calendar Plugin. I need to show event as a card already exist from my API to Table Calendar dynamically.

I'm so new for this package, How can I handle my case?

**Result API** :

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "All the revisions of current user ",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "1",
            "revision_date": "2021-05-30",
            "revision_location": "gafsa",
            "revision_title": "Une visite technique est important avant le 30-05-2021",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "0",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-26",
            "revision_location": "tyyu",
            "revision_title": "ygyyii",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": 8655,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "2",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-20",
            "revision_location": "STAR",
            "revision_title": "Votre prochain renovellement de l'assurance sera le 20-06-2021 avec l'agence STAR",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "3",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-20",
            "revision_location": "sfax",
            "revision_title": "véhicule en panne",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": 87654
        }
    ],
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

**Model** :

```
class Revision {
  int code;
  String message;
  Data data;
  String error;
  int status;

  Revision({this.code, this.message, this.data, this.error, this.status});

  Revision.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    error = json['error'];
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['code'] = this.code;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    data['error'] = this.error;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  RevisionInProgress revisionInProgress;

  Data({this.revisionInProgress});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    revisionInProgress = json['revision in progress'] != null
        ? new RevisionInProgress.fromJson(json['revision in progress'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.revisionInProgress != null) {
      data['revision in progress'] = this.revisionInProgress.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class RevisionInProgress {
  int id;
  int boxId;
  int userId;
  String revisionType;
  String revisionDate;
  String revisionLocation;
  String revisionTitle;
  Null kilometragePourVidange;
  String repeatRevision;
  int revisionStatus;
  Null kilometrageLastVidange;
  Null kilometrageRevision;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  RevisionInProgress(
      {this.id,
      this.boxId,
      this.userId,
      this.revisionType,
      this.revisionDate,
      this.revisionLocation,
      this.revisionTitle,
      this.kilometragePourVidange,
      this.repeatRevision,
      this.revisionStatus,
      this.kilometrageLastVidange,
      this.kilometrageRevision,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  RevisionInProgress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    assert(json['revision_title'] != null, 'revision_title is null');
    if (json['revision_title'] == null) {
      throw PropertyIsRequired('revision_title');
    }

    id = json['id'];
    boxId = json['box_id'];
    userId = json['user_id'];
    revisionType = json['revision_type'];
    revisionDate = json['revision_date'];
    revisionLocation = json['revision_location'];
    revisionTitle = json['revision_title'];
    kilometragePourVidange = json['kilometrage_pour_vidange'];
    repeatRevision = json['repeat_revision'];
    revisionStatus = json['revision_status'];
    kilometrageLastVidange = json['kilometrage_last_vidange'];
    kilometrageRevision = json['Kilometrage_revision'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['box_id'] = this.boxId;
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    data['revision_type'] = this.revisionType;
    data['revision_date'] = this.revisionDate;
    data['revision_location'] = this.revisionLocation;
    data['revision_title'] = this.revisionTitle;
    data['kilometrage_pour_vidange'] = this.kilometragePourVidange;
    data['repeat_revision'] = this.repeatRevision;
    data['revision_status'] = this.revisionStatus;
    data['kilometrage_last_vidange'] = this.kilometrageLastVidange;
    data['Kilometrage_revision'] = this.kilometrageRevision;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Event Screen** :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF050127),
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF010611),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              widget.title = 'Révision',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              //textHeightBehavior: ,
            ),
            elevation: 0.0,
            leading: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SideBar()));
              },
              child: Icon(CommunityMaterialIcons.segment),
            ),
            actions: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search, /*color: Colors.black87*/
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
            ]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    height: size.height * 0.05,
                    width: size.width * 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy       hh:mm:ss")
                              .format(DateTime.now()),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              letterSpacing: 1),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              CommunityMaterialIcons.calendar_plus,
                              color: KYellow,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _showAddDialog();
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: TableCalendar(
                    //events calendar
                    events: _events,
                    daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
                        weekdayStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        weekendStyle: TextStyle(color: KYellow)),
                    calendarController: _controller,
                    locale: 'fr_FR',
                    initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
                    //Calendar style
                    calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                        markersColor: Colors.white70,
                        canEventMarkersOverflow: true,
                        todayColor: KYellow,
                        selectedColor: KYellow,
                        todayStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.white)),
                    //header style
                    headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                      leftChevronIcon: Icon(
                        CommunityMaterialIcons.chevron_left,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      rightChevronIcon: Icon(
                        CommunityMaterialIcons.chevron_right,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      centerHeaderTitle: true,
                      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: KYellow),
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                      ),
                      formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: KYellow),
                      formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                    ),

                    startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
                    //ondaySelected
                    onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedEvents = events;
                      });
                    },
                    //calandar builder
                    builders: CalendarBuilders(
                      dayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          date.day.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: KYellow,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          child: Text(
                            date.day.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                      todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: KYellow.withOpacity(0.3),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          child: Text(
                            date.day.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                    ),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
              Column(children: [
                ..._selectedEvents.map(
                  (event) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      CommunityMaterialIcons.oil,
                                      color: KYellow,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      event,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: KYellow,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Text(event),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  event,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[400]),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        CommunityMaterialIcons.file_clock,
                                        size: 35,
                                        color: KYellow,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 30,
                                    ),
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        CommunityMaterialIcons
                                            .content_save_edit_outline,
                                        size: 35,
                                        color: KYellow,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (event == 'videnge') {
                                          showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                _buildUpdateVidengeEvent(
                                                    context),
                                          );
                                        } else
                                          showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                _buildUpdateEvent(context),
                                          );
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ))),
                  ),
                )
              ])
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**My Current Screen** :

[image]

Comment: Hey did you try `syncfusion_calendar` , I would recommend you trying it once